# How to display custom user profile plugin fields on "Edit account" page?

Tags: custom-field, acl, joomla-3.9, profile, editing

We are building a website with multiple authors using [PWT ACL](https://extensions.perfectwebteam.com/pwt-acl) to restrict their access to the users tab so that they don't mess with each other's profile or content.

I created a custom user profile plugin ("User Profile 5") so we can store their information, but I haven't been able to get it to show up on the Edit account page so that they can actually fill in the forms.

[image: "User profile 5" shows up under users tab]

[image: clicking edit account][image: User Profile 5 doesn't show up]

Comment: Welcome to JSE Gabriel.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your permissions are set accordingly to allow edit on custom fields.

Comment: Your answer has been automatically flagged as possibly low-value due to its length.  Can you perhaps [edit] your answer to be a little more generous about how to implement your advice?

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for taking the time to contribute.  Please take our [tour] and and consider introducing yourself by editing your profile.